# Llamar a un metodo en Angular 6

Tags: angular

Estoy comenzando con Angular 6, necesito llamar a un método en el HTML pero no se como hacerlo. la unica forma que he encontrado es asígnandolo a un evento pero lo que quiero es que el método se ejecute solo sin necesidad de hacer click en un botón o algo parecido. Como invoco al metodo en el html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes hacer uso de un enganche de ciclo de vida, que se invoca después de que Angular ha inicializado todas las propiedades de una directiva ligadas a datos. Defina un `ngOnInit()` como método para manejar cualquier tarea de inicialización adicional.

Esto te sirve para poder ejecutar funciones o métodos importantes que se requieren al momento de iniciar un componente en Angular.

Fuente: [Angular.io](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit)

**Ejemplo**

```
  ngOnInit()
  {
    //Declaracion de variables para activar clases nativas de Bootstrap = Active.
    this.claseInventario='nav-link active';
    //Declaración de variables del titulo de cada componente
    this.tituloComponente = 'Inventario';

    //Evalumos formulario
    this.evaluated = true;
    //Iniciamos el validador cuando inicie el controlador del componente
    this.registrarInventario = this.formBuilder.group({
            producto_inventario: ['', [Validators.required]],
            costo_inventario: ['', [Validators.required]],
            cantidad_inventario: ['', [Validators.required]],
            proveedor_inventario: ['', [Validators.required]],
            vencimiento_inventario: [null, []],
            orden_inventario: ['', []],
            invima_inventario: ['', []],
            lote_inventario: ['', [Validators.required]],
            bodega_inventario: ['', [Validators.required]],
            ubicacion_inventario: ['', [Validators.required]],
            observacion_inventario: ['', []]
    });
  };
```

Si te sirve, me lo haces saber, sino también...

Comment: Si me funcionó hermano. Había leído que el ngOnInit se usaba como una alternativa al constructor para inicializaciones mas complejas pero no me imaginé que servía para estos casos. Esa sería la única manera? es decir, no se puede invocar a un método en el html? como por ejemplo, colocando: Metodo(), o algo por el estilo ?

Comment: @JulianProg en versiones anteriores como `ng-init()` en la versión de AngularJS x1 se podía utilizar como directiva para realizar una inicialización de un método o función desde el `html`. El `ng-init` se ha ido y no volverá; Por lo que necesita inicializar explícitamente los campos en la clase de un componente (equivalente al alcance inicial). Te recomiendo que si mi respuesta te ha servido, la marques como respuesta aceptada. Gracias!

Comment: Ok, es decir que es la única forma de inicializar los métodos sin la interacción del usuario, Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, probablemente me veas preguntando otras cosas sobre Angular ya que estoy haciendo un portafolio con Angular y Bootstrap. Saludos!

Comment: Hola, si, en pocas palabras es lo mas recomendado! y dale, para eso existe la comunidad, ayudar para ser ayudado.

Comment: Los métodos como `onInit` son ciclos de vida de tu componente, esto quiere decir que es código que se puede ejecutar antes de cargar el componente, mientras se carga, cuando está cargado, cuando se está destruyendo, etc.